# Add-in Word Online: displayDialogAsync does not work "NotHttps"

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Our product uses function "displayDialogAsync" and everything was good, then this function was broken for a Word Online in Chrome browser.

**Example of code:**

```
 Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 80, width: 25, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);
```

**Below is the Error:**
[image]

*Details:*
The same code execute for Excel add-in and for Excel this function is working fine. Seems issue in word-web-16.00.js file after some updates.
Also we tried to use different parameters and host.
url has the same domain as add-in.

**Environment**:
O365 Word Online
Chrome browser

Comment: This looks like a bug, can you please post an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Done it - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1845